# Getting status(posts) from both logged in user and friends table, in php mysql

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

This is the situation, there are 3 tables Friends, Status and Users. I need to retrieve statuses and posts from logged in users as well as friends from the status table but the problem is how to join or inner join or union. The results either bring out just the logged in users post or none at all

Here are the tables

**USERS:**
[image: This is the Users table]

**FRIENDS:**
[image: The friends table with the relationship between user1 and user2]

**AND THE STATUS TABLE:**
[image: The status table]

Thanks to anyone who can help me, i have been racking my brain for the past week trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

```
select      *
from        status_table
where       user_id in (select user2 from friends where user1='logged_in_user') or user_id = 'logged_in_user';
```

This is an not efficient method, but for small data set it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response, i'll try it

Comment: Thanks but, the code only outputs the post by the logged in user and not his friends. Thanks for your help thoughs

Comment: Can you post the exact query you are using

Comment: is saw this one online just now as i was searching, its not working but it's similar     $sql = "


SELECT *
FROM `friends` AS `f`
LEFT JOIN `status` AS `s`
    ON
        `s`.`user_id` = $log_id AND
        `s`.`user_id` = `f`.user1 OR
        `s`.`user_id` = `f`.user2
LEFT JOIN `users` AS `u`
    ON `u`.`user_id` = `s`.`user_id`
WHERE
    $log_id = `s`.`id` AND
    `f`.user1  = `s`.`id` OR
    `f`.user2  = `s`.`id` AND
    `s`.`user_id` = `s`.`id`
GROUP BY `s`.id
";

Comment: Can post the query using my solution.. the above query seems to be using multiple join which is definitely unnecessary

Comment: From the table the logged in user is 4: oneil the post that oneil has done is just chitty and his friends from the table are jessica and miranda but this query only brings out chitty, his post only $sql = "
select      *
from        status
where       user_id in (select user2 from friends where user1='4') or user_id = '4';
";

Comment: Ok I got your problem If A is friend of B then there will be only one record A to B or B to A. That’s why the above query is not working you can add this to end of the query => or user_id in (select user1 from friends where user2=‘4’)

Comment: It works, you are a life saver. You just did a weeks worth of work in like 5 mins. i am sincerely and utterly grateful, i wish i could reciprocate this to you somehow.

Comment: @SilvaO'Neil glad it worked!!! Just accept the answer and give back to community. Happy coding.